# How to get the name of the key of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the name of the key name of an object?

In the example I want key to equal a, b and c.

```
let demo = { "a": valA, "b": valB, "c": valC };

$.each(demo, function (index, val) {
    let key = ??
});
```

Comment: in your code, `index` is already equal to `key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ES6 syntax, you have access to the `for ... in` loop, which can loop through objects.

```
const demo = { "a": valA, "b": valB, "c": valC };

for (const key in demo) {
  console.log(key);
}

// a
// b
```

Comment: `for...in` since ES1

Answer (score 2):

Use [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const demo = { "a": "valA", "b": "valB", "c": "valC" };

const keys = Object.keys(demo);

console.log(keys);
```